# Android app crashes when a button starts a client

Tags: java, android, android-studio, network-programming, client-server

I run a MainActivity class in which I add on onClick event and when I click on a fab it has to start up a client side class of a server system (the server side is on my computer, it's not involved here). Sadly, it crashes and I don't understand why. Fab2 is a floating action button.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
                        ...

fab2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Connect", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            ClientSide kb = new ClientSide();
            kb.serverInitialization();
        }
    });

public class ClientSide extends Thread{


public static final String SERVER_HOSTNAME = "localhost";
public static final int SERVER_PORT = 2002;
private static BufferedReader mSocketReader;
private static PrintWriter mSocketWriter;

public void run(){System.out.println("run");}

public void serverInitialization() {
    System.out.println("Thread activated!");
    // Connect to the chat server

    try {

        Socket socket = new Socket(SERVER_HOSTNAME, SERVER_PORT);
        mSocketReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        mSocketWriter = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
        System.out.println("Connected to server " + SERVER_HOSTNAME + ":" + SERVER_PORT);

    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        System.err.println("Can not connect to " + SERVER_HOSTNAME + ":" + SERVER_PORT);
        ioe.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(-1);

    }


    // Start socket --> console transmitter thread

    PrintWriter consoleWriter = new PrintWriter(System.out);
    TextDataTransmitter socketToConsoleTransmitter = new TextDataTransmitter(mSocketReader, consoleWriter);
    socketToConsoleTransmitter.setDaemon(false);
    socketToConsoleTransmitter.start();


    // Start console --> socket transmitter thread

    BufferedReader consoleReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    TextDataTransmitter consoleToSocketTransmitter = new TextDataTransmitter(consoleReader, mSocketWriter);
    consoleToSocketTransmitter.setDaemon(false);
    consoleToSocketTransmitter.start();

}
}
   class TextDataTransmitter extends Thread {

    private BufferedReader mReader;
    private PrintWriter mWriter;



     public TextDataTransmitter(BufferedReader aReader, PrintWriter aWriter) {

        mReader = aReader;
        mWriter = aWriter;
    }



    /**

     * Until interrupted reads a text line from the reader

     * and sends it to the writer.

     */

    public void run() {

        try {

            while (!isInterrupted()) {

                String data = mReader.readLine();
                MainActivity gg = new MainActivity();
                gg.updateTextField(data);
                mWriter.println(data);
                mWriter.flush();
            }

        } catch (IOException ioe) {

            System.err.println("Lost connection to server.");
            System.exit(-1);

        }

    }

}
```

The compiler jumps to the Thread so I guess that means that it tries to execute it... idk. Please, help, I will try to supply you with the needed information.

Comment: logcat for the exception?

Comment: @Bhargav, nothing remains in the logcat... it closes too quickly :/